# change print format of web page in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a page with multiple images on it. I want to print it as it shows on web page. 
here is the image of web page.

[image]

when I print it, It shows like below image

[image]

I want it to print it same like it is showing in web page.

Here is the code for showing image on dynamic divs.

```
 HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div.Attributes.Add("id", divId);
            div.Attributes.Add("class", divClass);
            div.Attributes.Add("runat", "Server");
            // div.Attributes.Add("style", "border:0px Solid black");
            if (divClass == "divleft")
            {
                diva.Controls.Add(div);
                div.Controls.Add(img);
            }
            else
            {
                divb.Controls.Add(div);
                div.Controls.Add(img);
            }
```

here is the code for print button

```
    <div id="DivMain" runat="server" class="page" >
        <div id="diva" runat="server" class="subpage">


        </div>
        <div id="divb" runat="server" class="subpage2">

        </div>
    </div>


  <div> <input type="button" value="Print Barcode" class="Logout" onclick="javascript: return PrintPanel();" /></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function PrintPanel() {
                //var panel = document.getElementById("<%=DivMain.ClientID %>");
          var panel = document.getElementById("ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_DivMain");
          //alert(panel.id);
          PrintElem(panel.id);

      }
      function PrintElem(elem) {
          var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
          mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title>');
          mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        //  mywindow.document.write('<div class=page-break></div>');
          mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title + '</h1>');
          mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
          mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

          mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
          mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

          mywindow.print();
          mywindow.close();
          return true;
      }
```

How to achieve it? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your css file to print page too:

```
...
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title>');
mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/*path to css*/"/>');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
...
```

If your print preferences are different, you can use below statement in your css to give different values for your print page:

```
@media print {
   …
}
```